# Check the nth item for each date start from the effective date

Tags: php

I have this effective date and the array start and repeat every 12 cycles. How do I check the item value of a specific date then?

I've tried to get the item value for specific date start from the effective date but it returns no value.

```
<?php
$start_date = '2019-01-01';
$end_date = '2019-01-30';

$item = array('a','a','a','a','o','o','b','b','b','b','o','o');
$i = 0;

while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $i = $i+1;
    $value = $item[$i];

    if($start_date == '2019-01-05') {
    echo "Date:".$start_date." Value:".$value;
    echo "</br>";
    }
    if($start_date == '2019-01-07') {
    echo "Date: ".$start_date." Value: ".$value;
    echo "</br>";
    }
    if($start_date == '2019-01-25') {
    echo "Date: ".$start_date." Value: ".$value;
    echo "</br>";
    }

    $start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
    }

?>
```

I expect the output to be like:

```
Date:2019-01-05 Value:o
Date: 2019-01-07 Value: b
Date:2019-01-25 Value:a
```

But I get:

```
Date:2019-01-05 Value:o
Date: 2019-01-07 Value: b
Date:2019-01-25 Value:
```

How to get nth value of the date every 12 cycles start from the effective date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not a loop. Loops are slow.

```
function getItem($date, $startDate){
  $item = array('a','a','a','a','o','o','b','b','b','b','o','o');
  $diff = date_create($startDate)->diff(date_create($date));
  if($diff->invert) return false; //error $date < $startDate
  return $item[$diff->days%12];
}

//example for use
$date = "2019-01-25";
$startDate = '2019-01-01';

echo getItem($date, $startDate);  //a
```

Comment: Good one. I'm thinking what is the concern of not using loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not resetting the array index once it goes past the length of your array. You can fix that by changing:

```
$i = $i+1;
```

to

```
$i = ($i+1) % 12;
```

Note that if you had PHP error reporting enabled (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)), you would have received an "undefined offset" Notice which would have helped you find this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought to use modolus operator. It's working. For your alternative solution, how do I choose another date besides the date in the array? Let say '2019-03-01', how to get the value for this date considering the effective date for 12 cyclesvalue start from '2019-01-01'?

Comment: The calculation of days $ day with / (24 * 60 * 60); is not correct. Not every day has 24 hours (the days when changing summer / winter time).

Comment: @jspit can't believe I forgot that.

Comment: @jspit I think it's okay because most of the country has 24 hours a day.

Comment: @Nick yes, this is what I'm looking for. Thank you for your solution, I learned something from this.

Comment: @jspit is correct, if you have daylight savings this code will not work.